# Understanding Overfitting in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, python, overfitting

i have built a fully connected neural network in order to predict a physical quantity. The dataset that I use is composed by 18 features and 1 label. The samples are 8504.
I ran a lot of time the code and I plot the chart that shows me the evolution of the training loss vs validation loss along the epochs in order to understand if it is a case of overfitting. I attacched some of this plot below.
Is it a case of overfitting? because in some case the two line seem to converge. But in other case the val loss is under the training loss, even if only slightly.

So the question are:
1) is it overfitting? If yes, why I can say that it is overfitting if the val loss is under the training loss? 
2) what can I do in order to reduce overfitting? because I've tried the most important one, like regularizaion of weigth and bias, dropout, data augmentation.

The code that I wrote is attached below. There are also the chart (the first 2 with 200 epochs, the second two with 100 epochs).
Let me know if you want other details.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from keras.regularizers import l2
# =============================================================================
# Scelgo il test size
# =============================================================================
test_size = 0.20
importance = 0.95

# =============================================================================
# Richiamo il dataset
# =============================================================================

dataset = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")

label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])

y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label)

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y*(y_max_pre_normalize-y_min_pre_normalize)+y_min_pre_normalize
    return final_value


# =============================================================================
# Split
# =============================================================================

X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = test_size, shuffle = True)

y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

# =============================================================================
# Normalizzo
# =============================================================================
scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)


scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)



# =============================================================================
# Creo la rete
# =============================================================================

from keras import backend as K
def r2_score(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true))) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )

from datetime import datetime
logdir = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir) 

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()
c= 1e-10
# ,kernel_regularizer=l2(c), bias_regularizer=l2(c)
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse', r2_score])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=False, batch_size=250
                    )

history_dict = history.history

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']
r2_score_train = history_dict['r2_score']
r2_score_val = history_dict['val_r2_score']

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_train_pred = denormalize(y_train_pred)
y_test_pred = denormalize(y_test_pred)




from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print("\n\nThe R2 score on the test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test1)))

print("The R2 score on the train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train_pred, y_train1)))
from sklearn import metrics

# Measure MSE error.  
score = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1)
print("\n\nFinal score test (MSE): %0.4f" %(score))
score1 = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1)
print("Final score train (MSE): %0.4f" %(score1))
score2 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1))
print(f"Final score test (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score2))
score3 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1))
print(f"Final score train (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score3))
```

Comment: What does overfitting mean to you?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Overfitting is when the model does not generalize to other data than the training data. Can you help me with my questions?

Comment: What about these plots makes you believe that the model does not generalize to the validation data?

Comment: Because I know that the model is good when the two curves converge. Than, in another quesdtion that I asked in another website they wrote me "Your validation curve is suspiciously below the training curve. " So in your opinion is it correct that val loss stay under the train loss?

Comment: The first plot appears to show the training and validation loss attain the same value. Do you think that is an example of the two curves converging?

Comment: Yes of course, but the 2° e 3° are not converging. Maybe the last one if I increase the n° epochs is ok.

Comment: The central figure in your opinion are correct? They are representative of a good model?

Comment: The goal is to minimize the loss. An overfit model has validation loss higher than training loss. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition+overfitting Your model has validation loss *lower* than training loss (for some losses). The question you need to answer is whether the *degree* of model misfit on those particular loss functions is important, or if you've sufficiently solved the problem that this amount of under-fit on those metrics can be safely ignored.

Comment: Ultimately, it's unlikely that you'll ever have training and validation loss achieve *precisely the same value* so the practical question becomes "Do I care about a difference that's *this* large?"

Comment: Ok, I understand what you said. But I ask to you the last question. Do I care about a difference that's this large?

Comment: That's up to you. What costs (financial or otherwise) are imposed on being wrong by this amount? Do you lose \$1 or \$1000? Does losing that much money harm you in a meaningful way?